# About block width.. what's going on here

Tags: css, html

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RtB6p.png]

See the picture above and this my CSS:

```
.activity {
    width: 70%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.activity .head {
    margin-top: 3%;
    text-align: center;
}

.activity .body {
    margin-top: 3%;
}
```

Why both of inline-blocks can't be in the same line?

```
<div class="body" style="background-color:red"> 
    <div style="background-color:green; display:inline-block; width:50%">
    </div> 
    <div style="background-color:blue; display:inline-block; width:49.6%">
    </div> 
</div>
```

When I set the second block width to `49.6%`, why does it begin in the next line?

Comment: please be more specific about your question! Do you want to achieve the markup from your image?

Comment: What's the problem?  Tell us, so we can help you fix it! :)

Comment: I edited the post to add it - for now see his comment

Answer (score 1):

The whitespace characters between the inline blocks take up some space, and as a result, increase the total width on the line box.

If you keep the inline-block elements next to each other in your HTML code, then it works as you might expect.

```css
.body div {
  height: 40px;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<div class="body" style="background-color:red"> 
<div style="background-color:green; display:inline-block; width:50%"></div><div style="background-color:blue; display:inline-block; width:50%"></div> 
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, i have tried "vertical-align: top;" but not working.
though, most of my elements has its own font style so "font-size:0;" may be fine.

Comment: Vertical align is not critical to the solution.  The key is that the two `div` elements are adjacent to each other in the HTML code.